# How to reverse engineer a progressive web app ?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I found this free PWA https://www.the-qrcode-generator.com and now wonder how I could do one such myself.

Since I couldn't find any access to its source code I wondered if it'd be difficult to reverse engineer.

I'm interested in building a PWA with QRCode functionality.

Comment: I was able to find out this web app uses the `https://github.com/Schibum/barcode.js` library which I'll try to use in a new pwa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know how they organized their rest API, the browser network tab will help a lot, just filter by XHR and examine all the call from the front end to be.

The front end is very hard to revers engineer, because most sites are served as minified bundles, so you can't see the original code.
You can however find some other information about what they used to build it, for example in the html source you can see some ng-* tags, which indicates that this is angular, you can also see that body has attribute data-ng-app meaning this is angularjs and so on.

For the QR logic you can see that there are no back end calls, meaning that it is written entirely in the client. I would search for already available solutions for that.

Answer (score 1):

This one was created with AngularJS v1.3.20. You can find the source in your console windows under Sources tab. You can easily beautify the code inside the window to make it readable.